# How do I uninstall a font installed using gnome-font-viewer?

Tags: gnome, uninstall, fonts

I installed a TrueType font by running:

```
$ sudo gnome-font-viewer somefont.ttf
```

and clicking the "install" button.

I would now like to uninstall that font (as it seems malformed and makes programs crash when used), but I can't find where it has been installed on the filesystem.

If I run the above command again, there is an unclickable "install**ed**" button where the "install" button used to be, but no option to **un**-install.

In hindsight I should have just put it in ~/.fonts but alas I did not.

I tried using font-manager, which does appear to have a "remove" button, but the font I installed does not appear there. It does appear in Gimp and Inkscape however, which is where it causes problems.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It turns out even though I ran it as root, it just installed it in `$HOME/.local/share/fonts/somefont.ttf` (but owned by root), not system-wide (as I had expected).

Comment: So how do you uninstall? Just `rm` the file?

Comment: @0__ yeah I think that's what I did. I don't know if it put any metadata elsewhere, but I doubt it